# Shopify cli: developing template from scratch shows default theme "Dawn"

Tags: shopify, shopify-template

I'm creating a Shopify template from scratch using Shopify cli.

After executing `shopify theme dev --store {my-development-store-url}`, `http://127.0.0.1:9292/` had shown my scratch-built template.

However, at some point, the url stated showing the default Shopify theme "Dawn".

Any update on my template hasn't been reflected to the endpoint.

The theme editor on Shopify admin page works fine.

I have no idea what is going on. Please help.

Answer (score 0):

Clearing all of the cookie values worked.
Still no idea what happened, though...